# Excel - How to add error handling to an array formula using OFFSET

Tags: excel, vba

I am populating a number of columns based on a lookup using OFFSET and MATCH. I want to add error handling so that the appropriate values are displayed in each of these columns - how can I do this in Excel and in Excel VBA?

Here are the details of the formula that I use:

I enter this formula as an array formula for the entire range B2:E100

=OFFSET(CustomerMaster!$A1,MATCH(A2,customerNumberList,0)-1,2,1,4)

I use the customerNumber in column A2 to fetch a 4 columns related to the customer in another sheet - CustomerMaster.

Now, if there is an error, I want all the 4 cells to have some value like "Unknown".

Comment: What sort of errors do you want to check for? Maybe add some of the code/formulae you are using?

Comment: What have you tried? `IFERROR` might work if you are looking for cell values. You need to be a lot more specific for this question to be answerable.

Comment: I have added the details of the formula I use

Comment: If this is related to your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12680552/973283), I do not understand. In that question you have 300 workbooks (one per customer) each with two worksheets. Each Worksheet 2 contains customer Id information while each Worksheet 1 contains a variable number of rows, perhaps products purchased. The data from all the Worksheet 1s is to be merged into a new consolidated worksheet. _Continued in next comment._

Comment: That requires extra columns in the consolidated worksheet containing the customer Id information from the Worksheet 2s. The easiest approach would be to copy the required values from each Worksheet 2 into the consolidated worksheet. I cannot see any easy or efficient way of using OFFSET.

Comment: @TonyDallimore, yes this is related to my earlier question, but this is another piece I do after transposing the columns to rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(CustomerMaster!$A1,MATCH(A2,customerNumberList,0)-1,2,1,4),"Unknown")
```

will work (at least if you have Excel 2007 or later).

Comment: can you please explain why we need to repeat the OFFSET formula again?

Comment: @Siraj you are checking if that `OFFSET` value is an error. If it is not, then you actually want that value, and need to retrieve it again. I'm not sure of an alternative to this without adding an intermediate column

Comment: I think you are confusing IFERROR with ISERROR - with the former there is no need to repeat - syntax is =IFERROR(formula,error_result)